# ruby on rails server wont start missing devise files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hi I am having a problem using devise with the ruby on rails server. My server was running fine until I ran a rake routes and realized the server is missing some devise files. Currently the ruby on rails server wont even start. I do remember moving my devise folder but cant remember where it should be for the server to come back online.

This is the error message I get in the console. Can someone please help? Thanks.

```
C:\Users\rich\treebook>rails server
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.1/lib/devise.rb:266:in `<m
odule:Devise>': cannot load such file -- devise/controllers/helpers (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.1/lib/devise.
rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundle
r/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundle
r/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundle
r/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundle
r/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundle
r/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundle
r/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundle
r.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Sam/treebook/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rail
s/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rail
s/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rail
s/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rail
s/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You were moving them from the folder where all of your gems were installed, `/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/` ?
try running `gem uninstall devise` and then again `gem install devise`

Comment: hey Zippe, thanks so much! I got it back online!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done 
`rails generate devise:install`?

Also I agree with Zippie that uninstalling and reinstalling may be the way to go.